# Merge two Datatables with different number and order of columns

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

How to merge two Datatables with different number and order of columns? The only matching columns (by name) of second table should be merged to first datatable-all other columns are ignored. If some columns in second are missing, null or empty values go to the column of first datatable.The second datatable is merged with first datatable according to the column order of the first one.I want to add second datatable at the bottom of the first datatable.

Comment: What did you try? What technology do you want to use? There are plenty of solutions and I guess that most of them consist mainly of hand written program code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the primary key property of the table you want to merge into.
Then call Merge with MissingSchemaOption = Ignore

Comment: Does it work without primary key on the datatable? I don't have any unique field in the datatable.Does it work when any of the columns missing in the second datatable?

Comment: Yes, you can merge without a primary key. The difference is that the rows from the second table will just be added to the end of the first table, it won't be able to merge individual rows. Maybe that is what you wanted?

Comment: yes exactly. I want to add at the bottom of the first table.